# Edit object in array directly in React is working but use hooks is not

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-state

```js
import { useState } from "react";

type Rule = {
  value: string;
  valid: boolean;
};

type RuleComponentProps = {
  rule: Rule;
  setValue: (value: string) => void;
  setValid: (valid: boolean) => void;
};

function RuleComponent({ rule, setValue, setValid }: RuleComponentProps) {
  function validator(value: string) {
    rule.valid = !!value;

    // Why below line doesn't work?
    // setValid(!!value);
  }

  function handleChange(e: any) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    validator(value);
    setValue(value);
    // rule.value = value;
  }

  return <input onChange={handleChange} value={rule.value} />;
}

export default function App() {
  const [ruleList, setRuleList] = useState<Rule[]>([]);

  function addRule() {
    setRuleList((prev) => [...prev, { value: "", valid: false }]);
  }

  function getSetValueMeth(index: number) {
    return (value: string) => {
      const newRuleList = ruleList.map((rule, i) => {
        if (index === i) {
          return { ...rule, value };
        }
        return rule;
      });
      setRuleList(newRuleList);
    };
  }

  function getSetValidMeth(index: number) {
    return (valid: boolean) => {
      const newRuleList = ruleList.map((rule, i) => {
        if (index === i) {
          return { ...rule, valid };
        }
        return rule;
      });
      setRuleList(newRuleList);
    };
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => addRule()}>Add rule</button>
      </div>
      {ruleList.map((rule, index) => (
        <p key={index}>
          Rule{index}:{" "}
          <RuleComponent
            rule={rule}
            setValue={getSetValueMeth(index)}
            setValid={getSetValidMeth(index)}
          />
        </p>
      ))}
      <p>{JSON.stringify(ruleList)}</p>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(ruleList)}>Show Rule List</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to edit the `valid` value in `rulelist` in above code. It's working when using `rule.valid = !!value;`, but when I change to `setValid(!!value);` method, the `valid` value didn't change even the `setRuleList` hooks called and with right updated `newRuleList`.

I created a CodeSandbox for this: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-demo-dfs236?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A17%2C29, you can debug it directly.

I know it's not proper to edit value directly in React, but why the hook not work? What's the proper way to accomplish my feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The enqueued state update by the `setValid` call in `validator` (*`getSetValidMeth`*) is wiped out by the enqueued state update by the `setValue` call in `handleChange` since each has a closure over the un-updated  `ruleList` state value at the time `handleChange` is called.

Using `rule.valid = !!value;` was mutating the *current* state reference so it persisted through to the next render cycle.

## Solution

Use a functional state update so each enqueued update correctly updates from any previous state value instead of whatever is closed over in callback scope.

```js
const getSetValueMeth = (index: number) => (value: string) =>
  setRuleList((ruleList) =>
    ruleList.map((rule, i) => (index === i ? { ...rule, value } : rule))
  );

const getSetValidMeth = (index: number) => (valid: boolean) =>
  setRuleList((ruleList) =>
    ruleList.map((rule, i) => (index === i ? { ...rule, valid } : rule))
  );
```

Full code:

```
function RuleComponent({ rule, setValue, setValid }: RuleComponentProps) {
  function validator(value: string) {
    setValid(!!value);
  }

  function handleChange(e: any) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    validator(value);
    setValue(value);
  }

  return <input onChange={handleChange} value={rule.value} />;
}

export default function App() {
  const [ruleList, setRuleList] = useState<Rule[]>([]);

  function addRule() {
    setRuleList((prev) => [...prev, { value: "", valid: false }]);
  }

  const getSetValueMeth = (index: number) => (value: string) =>
    setRuleList((ruleList) =>
      ruleList.map((rule, i) => (index === i ? { ...rule, value } : rule))
    );

  const getSetValidMeth = (index: number) => (valid: boolean) =>
    setRuleList((ruleList) =>
      ruleList.map((rule, i) => (index === i ? { ...rule, valid } : rule))
    );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => addRule()}>Add rule</button>
      </div>
      {ruleList.map((rule, index) => (
        <p key={index}>
          Rule{index}:{" "}
          <RuleComponent
            rule={rule}
            setValue={getSetValueMeth(index)}
            setValid={getSetValidMeth(index)}
          />
        </p>
      ))}
      <p>{JSON.stringify(ruleList)}</p>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(ruleList)}>Show Rule List</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works now, but i still confuse about why ```getSetValueMeth``` works but ```getSetValidMeth``` didn't.

Comment: @JackZhang It's because both are processed in the same callback scope and both just set the value directly, not taking any previous, *or intermediate*, state into consideration. `getSetValueMeth` would run and set the next state value, then `getSetValueMeth` would run and just overwrite it with *its* next state value. Using a functional state update fixes this and allows `getSetValueMeth` to update from the state `getSetValidMeth` just set. [Updating state based on the previous value](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) might help explain.